# checkbox not visible when value is not null

Tags: android, checkbox

i want to `set visibility` `Check-box` when server return value is not `null` but `check-box` is not `visible`

this is **my code**

```
    JSONObject json_Response = new JSONObject(response);
      String _RchAmount = json_Response.getString("pay_from_wallet");
      String _Remainbalance = json_Response.getString("ewalletbalance");
      String _InrPay =json_Response.getString("amt_collected");
          if(_Remainbalance==null)
             {
              _CheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              confirm_payWallet.setText("Pay from  eWallet Rs. " + _RchAmount);
              confirm_payWallet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              confirm_TotalWallet.setText("Your current eWallet balance is Rs." + _Remainbalance);
              confirm_TotalWallet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

**Myxml**

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/check_wallet"
    android:textColorHint="@color/MediumVioletRed"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pay_textView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/check_wallet"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text=""
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/pay_textView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pay_textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/status_wallet"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

i dont know where i am doing mistake Please help me

Comment: android:visibility="invisible" why dont you remove this from xml and set that from code also like you set for visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your condition is for `null` value

```
if(_Remainbalance==null)
```

If should be `!=null` if you want to visible when value is not `null`

```
if(_Remainbalance!=null && _Remainbalance.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
```

If you are getting null in string object than use `equalsIgnoreCase("null")`

Comment: @nEwDeV because you might be getting "null" in string, check my editted ans

Comment: is it really returning null or empty string i.e. "" ? that's totally different.

Comment: that purely depends on output , as he mentioed null in question so it might be null or "null".

Comment: @RRR thanks `if(_Remainbalance!=null)` is right now its working

Comment: use this  if(_Remainbalance!=null || _Remainbalance.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonObject.isNull(Key) instead of `if(_Remainbalance==null)` in if condition to check null value it will be work